# How to loop through a variable-length placeholder in TensorFlow?

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose that I have an input tensor as follows:

```py
x_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[1, None], name='x_inputs')
```

This is a placeholder with **variable-length inputs**.

Also, I have an embedding matrix:

```py
embeddings = tf.Variable(
    tf.random_uniform([vocabulary_size, embedding_size], -1.0, 1.0),
    name='embeddings')
```

I want to lookup the embeddings for each element of the input sequence and add them together to build a single embedding vector. Something similar to (in python):

```py
embed = tf.zeros([batch_size, embedding_size])

for element in range(num_inputs):
  embed += tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings,
                                  tf.cast(x_inputs[:, element], tf.int32))
```

If `num_inputs` is fixed, everything is ok.
The problem is that the value of `num_inputs` is changed during the training process and I need to calculate it inside the graph. I dont know how to calculate the above `for loop` in the graph based on the input values in `x_inputs`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`tf.nn.embeddings_lookup` can handle variable sized arguments:

```py
x_inputs = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=[1, None], name='x_inputs')
embeddings = tf.constant([[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]])

iterSession = tf.InteractiveSession()

embed = tf.squeeze(tf.nn.embeddings_lookup(embeddings, x_inputs))

iterSession.run(embed, feed_dict={x_inputs: [[0, 1, 0, 2]]})
# array([[1, 2, 3],
#       [4, 5, 6],
#       [1, 2, 3],
#       [7, 8, 9]], dtype=int32)

iterSession.run(tf.reduce_sum(embed, axis=0), feed_dict={x_inputs: [[0, 1, 0, 2]]})
# array([13, 17, 21], dtype=int32)
```

Note that `x_inputs` is of the type `tf.int32` directly, avoiding the cast.

---

If you wanted the length to be dynamic during the execution and were using the embeddings as an example, you can write it using `tf.foldl`:

```py
embed = tf.foldl(lambda a, x: a + tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, x),
                 tf.reshape(x_inputs, (-1,)), 
                 initializer=[[0, 0, 0]])
iterSession.run(embed, feed_dict={x_inputs: [[0, 1, 0, 2]]})
# array([[13, 17, 21]], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Thank you. I dont understand the role of `tf.squeeze`, your code is not compatible with single-length inputs, for example: sess.run(tf.reduce_sum(embed, axis=0), feed_dict={x_inputs: [[0]]})
returns "6"!

Comment: @AmirHJ Ah, right. I had put in the `squeeze` to remove a single 1-D axis. However, it acts greedily by default and removes any 1 sized dimensions it finds. We can, however, specify which axis to get rid of in `tf.squeeze` (i.e. the first level) and that should make it compatible with 1-sized inputs too.

Comment: Ahaa, The problem is with `axis` parameter of `tf.reduced_sum`, the final code is as follows:
`embeds = tf.nn.embedding_lookup(embeddings, x_inputs)` and then `embed = tf.reduce_sum(embeds, axis=1)`
Thank you @musically_ut